# Django admin image upload error "submitted file is empty"

Tags: python, django, image, django-models

I was trying to upload an image with the ImageField and one I select the image and click save it is throwing an error that the submitted file is empty.
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PW8g.png)

models.py

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also it has not created a media directory. is it because that I have a directory named media inside my static?
[media directory i created inside static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTxe9.png)

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Checked google for quick fixes.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had gone through your code I didn't see any possible error on your code, the only issue you had is that `Django gotcha` caught you, you don't recreate or create what Django used in it's internal logic to build your code for example naming your app module `auth or auths`, this will cause nuisance/weird behavior in your code.

Kindly do this:

```py
1.Change the name of the file in your static file you named from media to something else.

2. Make sure that you have imported pillow via pip

3. Ensure that your `static` is properly imported from Django conf like below:
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

Good luck!

Comment: thank you ! as it said my images were somehow empty. I did had the images in the right directory but somehow it was showing 0kb in size.